# Sort an array by ID and separate same ids in arrays

Tags: ios

I am trying to tackle the following sorting and separating, I have an array with IDs like 1,2,3,4,5,3,2,1.

Sorting  that array with NSPredicate is quite straightforward but how can i also separate same IDs in separate sub-arrays like [[1,1][2,2,],[3,3],[4],[5]]? I guess one option is to loop the sorted array and compare previous index ids, but I am wondering if any helper function exist in iOS, I am currently reading about NSOrderedSet but cant seem to find if it can help.

Comment: in swift of objective C?

Comment: Obj-C but swift is also welcome

Comment: You might consider `NSCountedSet`, `- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)anArray`. but you will loose the ordering of the IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of ordered and counted sets:

```
NSArray *array = @[@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@3,@2,@1];
NSOrderedSet *os = [[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
NSCountedSet *cs = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [@[] mutableCopy];

[os enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSMutableArray *countArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (int i = 0; i < [cs countForObject:obj]; ++i) {
        [countArray addObject:obj];
    }
    [sortedArray addObject:[countArray copy]];
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift , with functional programming:

```
let indexes = [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,1]
let notRepeatedIndexesSet = Set(indexes)
let notRepeatedIndexesArray = Array(notRepeatedIndexesSet).sorted(<)
let yourArray = notRepeatedIndexesArray.map{
    number -> [Int] in
    Array(count: indexes.filter { $0 == number }.count, repeatedValue:number)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Produces: `[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4], [5]]` which is the desired result. But "wow" on the code.

Comment: Swift 1.2 finally has Sets, you should use it in `distinct()`, as your current implementations has a bad complexity due to the `contains` call that will iterate over the array for each element.

Comment: this looks like a  great solution, but my final implementation of JSON objects filtering requires objective-c, still I upvote this answer.